# Comments not crawlable by search engines?

Tags: facebook-comments

I was wondering if Search Engine spiders can see the comments, when I open the source of the page the comments are not showing up (same as with disqus), so I'm assuming when the search engines crawl the page they won't see the comments either? Is this assumption correct? If so, is there a way to change this?

**Found the solution:**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

> How can I get an SEO boost from the comments left on my site?
>
> The Facebook comments box is rendered in an iframe on your page, and
>   most search engines will not crawl content within an iframe. However,
>   you can access all the comments left on your site via the graph API as
>   described above. Simply grab the comments from the API and render them
>   in the body of your page behind the comments box. We recommend you
>   cache the results, as pulling the comments from the graph API on each
>   page load could slow down the rendering time of the page.

Comment: I would imagine that different search engines would crawl differently. For example I heard Google will discover if you are using Facebook comments and then parse those (even though it doesnt exist in your html). But to be honest I can't remember seeing external commenting systems appear on Google for any site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only what get thrown to a crawl engine the crawl engine can see, hence these comments should be outputted in able to get crawled and saved into the SE database or whatever it uses to collect data about websites, you might check the headers the connection request came from, if it belongs to a crawl engine and that's called a user agent in our case humans (browsers), here you can find a way to detect crawlers using [PHP](http://www.cult-f.net/detect-crawlers-with-php/), after detecting it you force the comments to be shown in order to get crawled, here also a good resource on how to deal with crawlers from [Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/crawlers) itself.

Now if you're talking about Facebook comments, it's impossible to let them indexed by the crawler or SE, when a crawler attempt to visit one of the Facebook pages it won't be able to see users' data because of the login page, and if you are talking about Facebook plugins you may do what what I suggested above, article talking about [Facebook comments crawling](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/01/09/how-facebook-comments-impact-google-search-rankings/).

Comment: sorry I don't understand. This means that Google does not see the comments? How do you "force comments to be shown"? thank you

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly the comments are?

Comment: here you go: http://mugshots.com/US-Counties/Florida/Hillsborough-County-FL/Dustin-Robert-Crooms.6972085.html sorry couldn't find a less controversial example..

Comment: or even the comments here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: It's possible but require much work and I don't know if Google crawlers will understand facebook's comment system/encoding. Read this https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: And this is a helpful article for you: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/01/09/how-facebook-comments-impact-google-search-rankings/

Comment: ok thank you, I checked all comments in the examples I sent and couldn't find any of them in Google, so I'm guessing that by default google does NOT crawl them

Comment: did you check the last resource I gave?

Comment: yep, but those comments on the page are also not appearing in the serps... I don't know if what's written there is true

Comment: I think that Facebook enhanced it's privacy to block Google crawlers or Google crawlers are not yet crawling AJAX perfectly, but there are work arounds, anyway if you find this answer helpful go ahead an accept it :)